# Ionic - Can't build after installing File Encryption plugin

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework, encryption, build

I've created a blank project with Ionic and installed the File Encryption plugin. But without even writing any code, I get the following error when trying to build the project:

```
    C:\Users\Zel\Desktop\a\platforms\android\src\com\disusered\Safe.java:120: error: cannot find symbol

      CRYPTO = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(CONTEXT), new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());
                              ^
  symbol:   class SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain
  location: class Safe
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


BUILD FAILED
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Total time: 11.002 secs
(node:14276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\Zel\Desktop\a\platforms\android\src\com\disusered\Safe.java:26: error: package com.facebook.android.crypto.keychain does not exist
import com.facebook.android.crypto.keychain.SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain;
                                           ^
C:\Users\Zel\Desktop\a\platforms\android\src\com\disusered\Safe.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
      CRYPTO = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(CONTEXT), new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());
                              ^
  symbol:   class SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain
  location: class Safe
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Zel\Desktop\a\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:14276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

By running `ionic info` I get the following output:

```
    cli packages: (C:\Users\Zel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10
```

I have tried several things that I have found but nothing has worked.
I get the project to be built if I use Android 6.2.0 but that tells me that the plugin isn't installed when it actually is!.

The plugin version I'm using is the latest (2.0.1)

Hope you guys can give me a hand over here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

In the platforms/android/cordova-safe/starter-conceal.gradle change this

compile('com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.0@aar')
to this
compile('com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.1@aar')

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open `platforms/android/cordova-safe/starter-conceal.gradle`, then update the version of **com.facebook.conceal:conceal** from **1.0.0** to **1.1.3**, so the code should now be

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.1.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}
```